# Touched not working in Xcode simulator (apple official tutorial 'FoodTracker')

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on an official Apple tutorial to learn iOS.

But I did the same, but the touch does not work in the simulator.

I tried turning Xcode off and on and copying and pasting the example file but it still doesn't touch. Or is there anything else you should try?

I need help.

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {


    // MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var mealNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var photoimageView: UIImageView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Handle the text field’s user input through delegate callbacks.
        nameTextField.delegate = self
    }
    //MARK: UITextFieldDelegate
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        // Hide the keyboard.
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        mealNameLabel.text = textField.text
    }

    //MARK: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {

        // Dismiss the picker if the user canceled.
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        // The info dictionary may contain multiple representations of the image. You want to use the original.
        guard let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as?
            UIImage else {
                fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided folowing: \(info)")
        }
        // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.
        photoimageView.image = selectedImage

        // dismiss picker
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK: Actions
    @IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        // Hide the keyboard.
        nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()

        // UIImagePickerController is a view controller that lets a user pick media from their photo library.
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

        // Only allow photos to be picked, not taken.
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary

        // Make sure ViewController is notified when the user picks an image.
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func setDefaultLabelText(_ sender: UIButton) {
        mealNameLabel.text = "Default Text"
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: please simulator close and re-open simulator working fine. this is issue many time xcode 11.2.1

Comment: thanks. I'm already close and re-open, but not  working yet..

Comment: What exactly isn't working? The text field or the image picker? Do things work as expected on a real device?

Comment: thanks David. I did the same as in the tutorial, but there was no response to image clicks in the simulator, I think it's an image picker problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `isUserInteractionEnabled` as `true` with Storyboard and add `Tap Gesture Recognizer` and link (or update this link) `@IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary` with Storyboard

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Not in the picture, but I already connected Tap Gesture Recognizer and @IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary. 
It doesn't make sense to say add isUserInteractionEnabled..

Comment: I don't know why. I've added your code and added `Tap Gesture Recognizer` to the Image and activated manually `isUserInteractionEnabled` from Storyboard and project works on simulators correctly. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984924/ios-tap-gesture-issue-on-image-view) helps you

Comment: thanks Nikolaev. I try your links, but  thread triggered error.. I'll try again from the beginning. really thanks!